# Should the Illuminator badge be awarded multiple times?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, edit-and-answer-badges

I think that the [Illuminator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/248/illuminator) badge should be awarded multiple times. There is no reason why a few good (actually: subjective, broad) questions or answers to them should be worth multiple badges (Great Question, Famous Question and Stellar Question are all awarded multiple times), but continued efforts to improve the site in addition to large amounts of good answers isn't.

The Socratic Badge is awarded multiple times, and can be seen as the long-term badge for questions. The Illuminator badge is the long-term badge for answering and editing, so it would make sense that it would be awarded multiple times.

Some statistics:

This would give the following users more than one Illuminator badge:

- At least 7 Illuminator badges: One user on SO. (Total, 2 extra badges)
- At least 5 Illuminator badges: Two users on SO. (Total, 2 extra badges)
- At least 4 Illuminator badges: Four users on SO. (Total, 4 extra badges)
- At least 3 Illuminator badges: Five users on SO. (Total, 5 extra badges)
- At least 2 Illuminator badges: Seven users on SO, two users on Mathematics, one on TeX, LaTeX and friends. (Total, 10 extra badges)
- At least 1 Illuminator badge: Forty-four users on SO, nine on Mathematics, four on TeX, LaTeX and friends, two on Unix & Linux, one on Super User, one on Science Fiction and Fantasy, one on Drupal answers.

I don't think there should be many multi-awarded gold badges, but I think that Illuminator should be one of them, like Socratic.

Comment: Adding ten more badges isn't very many....

Comment: @NathanTuggy 21 actually. (ten times as the second badge, five times as the third, four times as the fourth, twice as the fifth, and once as the sixth or seventh). It is many when you consider that only 60 have been awarded on all sites so far.

Comment: [As recommended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without), I suggested an edit to this question in hopes that a Moderator will tag this old feature request with "status-review".  I strongly agree with the proposal, and the question has been received well by the community.